# Windows 8.1 Handle potentially different data types

Tags: c#, windows-8.1

I have a gridview which can fire a holding event on an item. The items consist of a `stackpanel`, `textblock` and an `image` which I am currently handling with the below code

```
private async void gvJobs_Holding(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
{

            JobLocal job = null;
            if(e.OriginalSource is TextBlock)
            {
                job = (JobLocal)((TextBlock)e.OriginalSource).DataContext;
            }
            else if (e.OriginalSource is Image)
            {
                job = (JobLocal)((Image)e.OriginalSource).DataContext;
            }
            else if (e.OriginalSource is StackPanel)
            {
                job = (JobLocal)((StackPanel)e.OriginalSource).DataContext;
            }
            ....code based on above result
}
```

but i feel there is a better way than using multiple if statements. I tried using `var` but I then cannot access `DataContext`
Could someone please advise on a better way to achieve my objective

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your UI Elements are derived from `FrameworkElement` so you can cast to this.

```
if (e.OriginalSource is FrameworkElement) {
    job = (JobLocal)((FrameworkElement) e.OriginalSource).DataContext;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a good situation to use c# 6.0 null-conditional member access operator and make it a one-liner

```
var job = (e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement)?.DataContext as JobLocal;

if(job != null) ...
```